# Pandas dataframe compare values == none / nothing / null

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have 2 columns in a pandas dataframe.

I want to check each `row` in `Column A` for any value that is `NOT == NaN`.

If a value is found then append the corresponding `row` with `'P'` IF `NaN` value then `'B'`

In excel I could use `=if(A1="","B","P"` assuming that the cell is `empty` and not `NAN`

I think my excel background is confusing me as to what is considered `empty` or `null` vs what is a `NaN` value.

```
<<Test Frame>>
Column A | Column B
1 NaN      NaN  
2 John     NaN
3 Dave     NaN
4 NaN      NaN
5 Michael  NaN

<<Desired Output>>
Column A | Column B
1 NaN      B 
2 John     P
3 Dave     P
4 NaN      B
5 Michael  P
```

I have done research on SO but couldn't find a fit for this particular purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pandas we have `np.where`

```
import numpy as np 

df['colB'] = np.where(df['colA'].isna(), 'B', 'P')
```